# Displaying categories article and tags in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

I want to display a category link to list all articles with the category.
I use Mongodb/Mongoid in this project, but I'm not sure about whether I'm doing this in a good way.

**Article model**

```
class Article
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

 field :title, type: String
  field :content, type: String

  belongs_to :user
  #kategorie
  belongs_to :article_category
```

**Article controler**

```
  class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
    def article
    @article = Article.order_by(created_at: 'desc').page params[:page]
  end

  def view_article
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

**ArticleCategory model**

```
class ArticleCategory
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps


  field :name, type: String

  has_many :articles


end
```

**routes**

```
  get 'article', to: 'articles#article'
  get 'article/:id', to: 'articles#view_article', as: 'view_article'
```

I want to make something like that. There is an `Article` and below is a category link. I click on this link and I see a list of articles in that category. Should I make an `ArticleCategory` controller? And what about routes in `categories`?

Comment: Yes, as far as I understand your problem you should add the controller. For the additional routes you should understand Rails routings, especially nested routes: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Comment: Thanks. How should i display a category anchor in my Article ?  **<%- @article.each do |single| -%>**          **<%= single.article_category -%>** because by this i'm getting: **#<ArticleCategory:0x11a77370>**

Comment: Something like `<%= link_to single.article_category.name, single.article_category -%>`. This can be slightly different depending on your configuration.

Comment: It is not working, i'm getting " undefined method `article_category"

Answer (score 0):

Since you have an `ArticleCategory` model, then yes, it makes sense to have an `ArticleCategoryController`. For the routes, I would make your `routes.rb` file look like this:

```
resources :article_categories do
  resources :articles, shallow: true
end
```

That way, the routes are nested (because articles `belong_to` article_categories), but you can access articles directly without having to know its parent category. To read more on routing (and particularly nesting), [look at this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources).

Comment: I don't know how the ArticleCategoryController should look like. The main route is : **http://localhost:3000/article**

Comment: Your `ArticleCategoriesController` (notice plural categories) should be similar to your `ArticlesController`. Depending on what actions you want (new, edit, show, etc), there should be methods whose names match the actions.

Comment: I use a rails admin, so i want to manage it with admin panel. I sill have a problem with displaying and choosing specific category.

Comment: And that problem is...?

Comment: In Article view. I want to display a category below the article post and it is not working ** <%= link_to single.article_category.name, single.article_category -%> **

Comment: When you say `<%- @article.each do |single| -%>`, you are taking an individual `article` and trying to loop over that. That isn't going to work. If `@article = Article.all`, then that will work. OR, change your link to: `<%= link_to @article.article_category.name, @article.article_category -%>`

Comment: I get undefined method " `article_category' for #<Mongoid::Criteria"

Comment: Now you're on the opposite end. You have a Criteria (think of it as an array) and are trying to call a method that belongs to a single `article`. Go back to `single.article_category.name`, as long as `single` is a single `article`.

Comment: I'm back and i have a 'NoMethodError at /article undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass '. I don't get it!

Comment: That's because `single` doesn't have an `article_category` associated with it. It returns `nil` and so it gives an error when you try to call `nil.name`. Unfortunately, this is really getting beyond the scope of this question. I'd check out some Rails guides to truly understand what is going on and how to build a simple site before proceeding.